# How do I implement the autocomplete functionality in Webforms?

Tags: javascript, webforms, ajax

I have a drop down box with college names that has 9000 options to choose from. I am unable to use the drop-down field in Webforms.

Is there a way to use an autocomplete in a text field for Drupal 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Autocomplete is implemented in Drupal through AJAX. When users type
>   into a textbox, code on the client page dynamically loads new data
>   from the server (a Drupal website) and uses this data to update the
>   user display (provide a drop-down list of matching options, which the
>   user can select from).

Available autocomplete functions (D6):

- user_autocomplete() - Use this function to load matching user names.
- taxonomy_autocomplete() - Use this function to load matching taxonomy terms.

If you want to have your own autocomplete function it is also possible.
Please see a full article on this subject on drupal.org ["Textfield that uses autocomplete"](http://drupal.org/node/854216)
to see how to build a custom autocomplete function.